Using Whisper AI for transcription from Polish - encoding error?
I am trying to transcribe audio files in Polish to text using the Whisper Open AI. I am encountering an error which seems to be about encoding the text (possibly because of Polish letters such as ś, ż etc.)? When I run the same command to transcribe audio in English, the programme transcribes it with no issues. I've read the "help" of Whisper but there is no information on encoding (that I can find). Any tips to fix this?
The command:
whisper audio.wav --language Polish > transcriptPL.txt  
(I also tried it without setting language to Polish; for English, just "whisper audioEnglish.wav > transcriptEN.txt" works well)
The error code:

C:\Users\agata\Desktop\Transcripts WP4> whisper audio.wav > transcriptPL.txt
C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py:115: UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
  warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 478, in cli
    result = transcribe(model, audio_path, temperature=temperature, **args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 349, in transcribe
    print(make_safe(line))
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 110-111: character maps to <undefined>

C:\Users\agata\Desktop\Transcripts WP4>


did you find any solution?
